# When we stop a service using intent, is it a must that the extra data same as the previous intent?

Tags: android

Let's say, we start the service in the following manner.

### Start the service

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, X.class);
intent.putExtra(X.TOKEN, "ABC");
startService(intent);
```

---

If we create an Intent with different extra data, will the previously started service be stopped?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, X.class);
intent.putExtra(X.TOKEN, "DEF");
// Will this stop the previous started service?
stopService(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When we stop a service using intent, is it a must that the extra data same as the previous intent?

No. Extras are not used to identify the component that is the destination for an `Intent`.

> If we create an Intent with different extra data, will the previously started service be stopped?

Yes, though the extras are useless in that case — I do not think that the service has any access to them. So, you could skip the code that adds those extras, if that is convenient.

Comment: "I do not think that the service has any access to them" - Can I get more info on this? As, I thought a started `IntentService`, can have access to extra data from `onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent)` ?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng: `onHandleIntent()` of an `IntentService` is given a copy of the `Intent` supplied to `startService()`. Your question is about `stopService()`; `Service` has no callback for this. `onDestroy()`, for example, does not get passed an `Intent`.